# Sudoers, Specific Programs & Said programs arguments

Tags: server, 22.04, sudo, visudo

I have a /etc/sudoers.d file which I want to run a program (asterisk) WITH arguments as a user (zabbix). So far I have tried:

```
zabbix ALL = NOPASSWD: /etc/path/to/my/script.sh
```

And

```
zabbix ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /etc/path/to/my/script.sh
```

which all the script does is run `sudo /usr/sbin/asterisk -rx "pjsip show channelstats"`. I've tried to run this command directly in the sudoers file but even when it then looks like.

```
zabbix ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/asterisk -rx "pjsip show channelstats"
```

And I've also tried escaping the quotes with no luck, which looks like.

```
zabbix ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/asterisk -rx \\"pjsip show channelstats\\"
```

It still asks me for a password. even when I change ALL params to the user 'asterisk' or even 'root' it still asks for a password. When I goto Zabbix (Monitoring Server) and try to retrive said data it get this error message.

```
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper

sudo: a password is required
```

How ever I can get it to work if I just give it the executable, just not with the params which having access to Asterisk without any specific params is a really REALLY bad practise. How can I make it not ask for the password?

P.S I'm always using Visudo for editing the Sudoers file/s.

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried to escape the quotes in the sudo command: `sudo /usr/sbin/asterisk -rx \"pjsip show channelstats\"` ?

Comment: @Marco 
`/etc/sudoers.d/pjsip.show.zabbix:1:56: syntax error
zabbix  ALL=(asterisk) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/asterisk -rx \"pjsip show channelstats\"
                                                       ^
What now?
`
So it seems I can only use the double slash like I've used above in my post.

Comment: No escape in the config, escape quotes in the command you run.

Comment: @Marco I did escape the quote with \" and I got the error above. If I use \\" Visudo exits fine and dosen't complain.

Comment: Again: NO escapes in the sudoer file. Use escapes on the commandline.